# Badge on tile in circle

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

How can I set badge with digits on tile in black circle like Outlook and Skype?
[image]

I have white logo background (business requirement) and white count not visible.

Comment: The Black Background is for Windows Mobile. If you use the same app on desktop, it will be transparent. This is by design and according to official microsoft documentation, they do not show/say this can be fiddled with. Although I want to point out that in the screenshot you shared above, pretty much all Icons are White. Skype is Blue but Center Icon is White. So it would be helpful if you can rethink on how your icon should look like. I say leave padding around the corners so that Badge can show perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on Microsoft Docs about badges: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-badges

Comment: Unfortunately, This article not contains info about black circle.